# I have 2 Tables that i'm Trying to Query with same Column

Tags: sql

I have two tables, `player` and `friend`. I'm trying to query information from both of them to retrieve the items

```
player_id (friend), 
friend_id (friend), 
nickname (player), 
FriendsNickname (Dynamic), 
relation (friend)
```

I created this SQL query to try to retrieve the items, but it failed on my part.

```
SELECT 
   friend.player_id,
   friend.friend_id,
   player.nickname, 
   (SELECT distinct player.nickname 
    FROM player, friend 
    WHERE player.player_id = friend.friend_id) as FriendName,
   friend.relation,
FROM 
   friend, player
```

but it returns the correct ids, nickname but not the correct friendname

```
"76561199766508009" "76561200657240053" "RedReaper" "CallumC"   "3" "NULL"
"76561199766508009" "76561200657240053" "CallumC"   "CallumC"   "3" "NULL"
"76561199766508009" "76561200657240053" "CrotchMan" "CallumC"   "3" "NULL"
"76561199766508009" "76561200657240053" "Callum Carmicheal" "CallumC"   "3" "NULL"
"76561199766508009" "76561200657240053" "ReconTheCat"   "CallumC"   "3" "NULL"
"76561199766508009" "76561200657240053" "redreaper" "CallumC"   "3" "NULL"
"76561200657240053" "76561199766508009" "RedReaper" "CallumC"   "3" "NULL"
"76561200657240053" "76561199766508009" "CallumC"   "CallumC"   "3" "NULL"
"76561200657240053" "76561199766508009" "CrotchMan" "CallumC"   "3" "NULL"
```

The SQL is supposed to return the values player id, friend id, nickname from player table, and generate the friends name using the information given (it does that but just comes back with same name every time), relation.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Just do regular `join`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle

Comment: Its a C++ application that connects to the DB, im using SQLiteBrowser to open it, the file is db3

Answer (score 1):

If i am understand correctly you are looking for this

```
SELECT 
   f.player_id,
   f.friend_id,
   p.nickname,
   f.nickname as friendname, 
   f.relation,
FROM 
   friend f
 inner join  player p on p.player_id = f.friend_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner join answer should be correct, but you can also use 'old style' syntax by just moving your subquery in the WHERE clause and doing an old style join there:

```
SELECT
   f.player_id,
   f.friend_id,
   p.nickname,
   f.nickname,
   f.relation,
FROM friend f, player p
WHERE f.friend_id = p.player_id
```